# Seeding many PRNGs, then having to seed them again, what is a good quality approach?

Tags: c, random

I have many particles that follow an stochastic process in parallel. For each particle, there is a PRNG associated to it.
The simulation must go through many repetitions to get average results. For each repetition, an exclusive PRNG seed should be chosen for each particle before the simulation begins.

For the first time I just get the `seed = time(NULL)` as seed for particle1. For the rest I just do `particle2 = seed + 1`, `particle3 = seed + 2`, etc.. , so all particles end up having a different seed.

At each repetition, the plan is to add an offset to that initial seed obtained from `time(NULL)`, such as `seed = seed + all_particles_offset;`
and then assign a different seed to each particle using the approach described earlier. 
My question is if this approach will lead to acceptable randomness quality? I am not concerned with security, just the quality of the random numbers running in parallel and the fact that the process is re-seeding from time to time.

By the way, the PRNG used is the PCG.

Comment: The quality of the random numbers depends on the algorithm as much as the seeds.  If the algorithm is good, the consecutive seeds will yield distinct sequences of numbers — you should be OK.  But if the PRNG is not much good, then there are problems, fixable by upgrading the PRNG and the size of seed that the alternative algorithm takes.  You should worry about whether `time()` makes a good seed.  Can you read from `/dev/urandom` to get a seed instead?

Comment: I see. Yes the program can use /dev/urandom. Based on the information about PCG, i see it as a good PRNG (pcg-random.org). The fact that all seeds were sequential was worrying me but if its how you say then it should be ok for all repetitions.

Comment: Note that if you use the time as an initial seed and you start a second run of the simulation less than N seconds after the first run starts — where N is the number of particles — you will get some particles in the second simulation using the same sequence of random numbers as some different particles in the first simulation.  You'll have to decide whether that matters or not.  Presumably, you'll be recording the relevant information about the seeds so you could reproduce any given run by setting the seed to a known value rather than always choosing a new seed from `time()` or `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: Yes I was aware of that. Actually I just read time(NULL) once. because for the repetitions i just add a large offset to the seed. Each repetition is another offset added, but I never read time(NULL) again. Will that work?

Comment: You could generate all your other seeds from the first seeded PRNG instead of adding a constant value.

Comment: @indiv,  I tried it, but I was not a good practise because of the birthday paradox, which is amplified by the fact that there are 1 million particles covering a range of possible seeds, so there is a chance that one repetition will fall into the already used region.

Answer (score 2):

The time is not a good seed as it's too predictable. It also runs the risk of getting reused if you need seeds frequently. To avoid this, it's normal to permute the time with something else like the process and/or thread ID.

What's even better is to get the seed from your operating system's source of randomness like [`/dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) or the non-blocking version `/dev/urandom`. This will use environmental noise and other sources to give you a good random seed.

You can combine both of them together, this is what [Ruby's Random#new_seed](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Random.html#method-c-new_seed) does.

```
    /* This gets a seed from /dev/urandom */
    fill_random_bytes(seed, sizeof(*seed));

    /* This further permutes the seed with the time and pid */
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    seed[0] ^= tv.tv_usec;
    seed[1] ^= (uint32_t)tv.tv_sec;
#if SIZEOF_TIME_T > SIZEOF_INT
    seed[0] ^= (uint32_t)((time_t)tv.tv_sec >> SIZEOF_INT * CHAR_BIT);
#endif
    seed[2] ^= getpid() ^ (n++ << 16);
    seed[3] ^= (uint32_t)(VALUE)&seed;
#if SIZEOF_VOIDP > SIZEOF_INT
    seed[2] ^= (uint32_t)((VALUE)&seed >> SIZEOF_INT * CHAR_BIT);
#endif
```

You could pluck their random seed code from [random.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/random.c).

---

To avoid having to do so many reads from `/dev/random`, which can run out of entropy, you can instead do as [@indiv suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946553/seeding-many-prngs-then-having-to-seed-them-again-what-is-a-good-quality-appro/36946768?noredirect=1#comment61452586_36946553): seed a PRNG to generate more seeds. The up side is you only need one good seed. The downside is it *might* leave you vulnerable to flaws in the PRNG.

This is effectively what `/dev/urandom` does, it uses `/dev/random`'s true randomness to seed its own PRNG to ensure there are always random numbers. You could just read from `/dev/urandom` for your seeds. The upside is this adds another PRNG which may cancel out any flaws by seeding your PRNGs with output from the same PRNG algorithm... or it might make them worse. The downside is you don't know how `/dev/urandom` is generating those seeds and it will change from platform to platform.

---

Any of this is better than using `time` or `seed +1`, `seed + 2`, ...

Comment: thanks I am right now changing the code to read an integer value from /dev/urandom. I guess I will have to be careful though for the case when the seed read is close to overflow, as all other particles use their corresponding offset to that seed. Or maybe it works too.

Comment: @CristobalNavarro What do you mean by "the seed read is close to overflow"?

Comment: I was pointing the case when for example the seed is close to MAX_UINT, and the million particles get their corresponding seed like particle_i = seed + i. But it seems that overflow is no harm, it will just loop and begin from 0, using unsigned values. There is also a matter of performance, I need to get all seeds at the same time in parallel, and also from time to time i need to get a global seed (the repetitions). I could build an array of all the seeds fetched from /dev/urandom/ but that is not the nices approach for my context as it introduces overhead.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of the birthday paradox, i will try getting a new /dev/urandom seed for each repetition and see how it goes.

Comment: @CristobalNavarro If you need to seed a million PRNGs I'd suggest either urandom or seeding one PRNG very well and drawing numbers from that to generate more seeds. Do not use seed+n as your seed generation algorithm.

Comment: If the PRNG uses the generated values as the next seed, using the return values from a first PRNG as seeds for a second would lead to them returning the same sequences, one step off. Given: `int main(void) { unsigned seed0 = 123456; srand(seed0); int rv0 = rand(); int rv1 = rand(); int rv2 = rand(); srand(rv0); int rv3 = rand(); int rv4 = rand(); printf("S0 = %u, R0 = %d, R1 = %d, R2 = %d, R3 = %d, R4 = %d\n", seed0, rv0, rv1, rv2, rv3, rv4); return 0; }`, on Mac OS X I get: `S0 = 123456, R0 = 2074924992, R1 = 277396911, R2 = 22885540, R3 = 277396911, R4 = 22885540`. Note the repeats.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You may be right, but I am immediately suspicious of anything using rand(). I'm on a phone and can't check with a better PRNG.

Comment: Yes, me too; but with multiple PRNGs, you might be using `nrand48()` or something else.  The issue is that if the output of one cycle of the PRNG becomes the seed for the next, then feeding successive values from the first PRNG as seeds for the second (up to the one millionth if the question is to be believed) might end up with each of them generating the same sequence.  A decent quality PRNG shouldn't run into that problem (`nrand48()` doesn't).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried it out using the OP's PRNG and it seems fine. I even deliberately disabled its output sequencer to ensure the seed is the only source of entropy. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/schwern/5d0d1ea3c1817fbba0d0d50c1d7b636b), could you verify?

Comment: @Joey Rather than dumping a FAQ on us, could you point out which parts apply to this answer? Or should it be its own answer?

Comment: I missed the "BTW, I'm using PCG as my PRNG" line.  I know nothing of that as yet.  I'll experiment.  However, it's unlikely to be simplistic enough to run into the problem.

Comment: thanks for the interest, I will study these answers and provide news as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Cristobal, with PCG or similar PRNG (which uses fast logarithmic skip-ahead), you don't need to handle multiple seeds. One seed is sufficient. You seed PRNG once before all threads/workers start and that's it.

You set how many RNG calls are needed per one event - N_part. You set how may events are per thread - N_evt.

And then after you started your workers, in each worker you have to do

```
pcg rng(seed);
rng.skip_ahead(worker_id*N_part*N_evt); // whatever it is called in PCG

for(int k = 0; k != N_evt; ++k) {
    int used_rngs = simulate_particle();
    // overlap check
    rng.skip_ahead(N_part-used_rngs); // move to the next particle
}
```

Thus, you have absolutely controllable simulation, you know if you overlap, each particle start at the same rng state, so it is totally reproducible for debugging etc

Comment: seems very simple and elegant. I will try it. How about varying the sequence of the PRNG state, so that each thread handles a private state with the common seed, but varying the sequence number ? would that work too?

Comment: @CristobalNavarro well, each thread starts with its own private PRNG state, but right at the thread start those states are exactly the same. As soon as thread start running before simulation it will advance state by worker_id*N_part*N_evt. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @CristobalNavarro what I described is basically how well-known MCNP code system done it. Basically, all results shall be reproducible whether you're running on the single CPU, multithreaded or on MPI cluster, and RNG overlap shall be controlled. Simple requirements, elegant solution

Comment: i think, what I was refering is that in PCG the initialization function of a PRNG state is of the form init( &state, seed, sequence). So for one seed, there are 2^32 or maybe more sequences available. I assume that each sequence offers a unique path of pseudo-random values.